# How to allow Tagged email addresses in Qmail?

Tags: linux, postfix-mta, qmail

Like we use recipient_delimiter in Post-fix such that if email address is "abc@host.com" then if we set "recipient_delimiter" to "+" (plus sign) in the /etc/post fix/main.cf file, now even if someone send an email on "abc+foo@host.com" or "abc+bar@host.com" then it will be delivered to the mailbox of "abc@host.com" only that is the plus sign and the content after the plus sign is ignored.

My problem is I want to achieve same in Q MAIL, can someone suggest me how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

In qmail, these are called 'extension addresses'.  Usually, the minus symbol is used as the delimiter instead of the plus symbol, but the functionality is the same as what you are describing, and it may be possible that the delimiter is configurable.  See http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#extension-addresses for more info.

Comment: In order to change the default delimiter used in qmail extension addresses, you must change the *dash* field specified for the recipient in `/var/qmail/users/assign` and then run `qmail-newu` to rebuild the cdb. This will require the `.qmail` files match the new delimiter, e.g., `.qmail-default` will need to be renamed to `.qmail+default`. Scripts that manage these files (e.g., qmailadmin) may not be aware to generate files with the new delimiter.